# Want to create new table from the findings from original table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am quite new to Postgresql.I have a Postgres table like this:

| createdat | pageTitle | sessionId | text | device | deviceserial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 08:55:10 GMT+0000 | submit option | null | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:05:11 | quick check | 88958d89c65f4fcea56e148a5a2838cfhdhdhd | hi | Android | 6625839827 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 08:59:10 GMT+0000 | submit option | null | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:07:11 | quick check | 88958d89c65f4fcea56e148a5a2838cfhdhdhd | hi | Android | 6625839827 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:01:10 GMT+0000 | submit option | null | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:09:11 | quick check | 88958d89c65f4fcea56e148a5a2838cfhdhdhd | hi | Android | 6625839827 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:03:10 GMT+0000 | submit option | null | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:09:11 | quick check | 88958d89c65f4fcea56e148a5a2838cfhdhdhd | hi | Android | 6625839828 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:03:10 GMT+0000 | submit option | null | launchComponent | Android | 636363636891 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:13:11 | quick check | 88958d89c65f4fcea56e148a5a2838cfhdhdhd | hi | Android | 6625839828 |
| Wed Sep 02 2020 09:06:10 GMT+0000 | submit option | null | launchComponent | Android | 636363636891 |

I grouped by this table by deviceserial with this command :

```
SELECT 
    deviceserial, 
    DATE_PART('minute', max(createdat)::timestamp - min(createdat)::timestamp) AS time_difference  
FROM 
    devices 
GROUP BY deviceserial;
```

Then the result is this bellow.Now I want to create a new table named "device_usage" from this columns deviceserial,device and usage values from below  and another column for id.After that I want to copy "device_usage" table to another database.How can I do that?I could not find a good solution.

| deviceserial | device | usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 636363636891 | Android | 3 |
| 636363636890 | Android | 8 |
| 6625839827 | Android | 29 |
| 6625839828 | Android | 4 |

Comment: You can insert the rows into a table or use `create table as`.

Comment: Not understanding this: '...finding with index to another database'? Can you provide more information?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you.More information added.

Comment: You can't do that directly. You would need to do `CREATE TABLE AS ...` as GordonLinoff suggested. Then you could do `pg_dump -d the_db -t the_table -f the_table.sql` and then `psql -d other_db -f the_table.sql`.  Another option would be to setup [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) on the other database and link to the table in the first database.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

- connect to both databases
- Run a `CREATE TABLE` statement with the appropriate column definitions on the second database. The `id` column is created as

  ```
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
  ```
- Run your query on the first database and fetch the results row by row.
- For each row, run an appropriate `INSERT` statement on the second database. That statement won't insert to `id` so that the column is filled with the autogenerated value.

These steps are for a solution with a program.

If you want to do it by hand (i.e., a one time task), move the data with `COPY`. Using `psql`, moving the data could look like

```
\connect db1
\copy (SELECT /* your query */) TO 'datafile'
\connect db2
\copy newtable (deviceserial, device, usage) FROM 'datafile'
```